# Does MAAS Cluster Controller API URL need to setup to Internal Network and not LAN Network

Tags: networking, server, maas

MAAS 1.9 - Ubuntu 14.04.4

Wondering if the MAAS Cluster Controller API URL need to setup to Internal Network and not LAN Network..... My Internal network is 10.x.x.x on eth1  and not accessible from my computer browser ie i cannot http://10.x.x.x/MAAS to it........

Currently the address is set to http://172.x.x.x/MAAS and it is accessible from my computer browser but it unable to commission any nodes......and getting Status Failed commissioning status.........

Also do i have to add the MAC address of all the machines manually for MAAS to discover ... as i am not finding any option for MAAS to auto discover any new devices.....Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You 'external' connection should be set by using...

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-cluster-controller
```

Your 'internal' connection should be set using...

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-region-controller
```

Whatever you set your internal to, is the network that your nodes should exist within.  You shouldn't have to add any mac addresses, aslong as PXE is enabled on your nodes, when they boot they should be able to find maas, and then run through the boot, and then shut off.  Once they're off, you should see them in maas.

You need to obviously configure your IPMI, or power control settings as well.  Those IPs should exist within your 'internal' network as well.  They don't have to, but if they are outside that network, maas has to be aware of that network and be able to connect to it as well, potentially eth2.